# How to clone a structure between dimensions?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

The `/clone` command is used to clone structures from one location to another.

The `/execute in` command is used to change the dimension the command is executed in.

Say I want to clone a block from the Overworld coordinates (0, 0, 0) to the Nether coordinates (12, 23, 34).

```
/execute in minecraft:overworld run clone 0 0 0 0 0 0 12 23 34
```

uses both coordinates in the Overworld.

```
/execute in minecraft:the_nether run clone 0 0 0 0 0 0 12 23 34
```

uses both coordinates in the Nether.

I need the (0, 0, 0) to be in the Overworld, and the (12, 23, 34) to be in the Nether.

How do I clone a structure between dimensions?

Structure blocks can probably accomplish this, but I would prefer an answer without one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## 1.19.4 update

As of 1.19.4, the `/clone` command has been supplemented with additional options to choose separate dimensions for source and destination.

These options can be exercised by adding `from <dimension name>` or `to <dimension name>` before entering the respective coordinates.

For example:

```
clone from minecraft:overworld 0 0 0 0 0 0 to minecraft:nether 12 23 34
```

Answer (score 6):

What i could see from the wiki the /clone command cannot send structures from one dimension to another.

Theoretically you could scan through all the blocks in the structure. and send the scan results in falling sand blocks to the other dimension (just make sure to place a block they can fall on) but this is far from instant and i'd use structure blocks.

You can save the structure to minecraft:autoclone (can be any namespace)

```
/setblock ~ ~ ~ minecraft:structure_block{mode:"SAVE",posY:1,name:"minecraft:autoclone",sizeY:10,sizeX:10,sizeZ:10,author:"<yourname>",showboundingbox:1b} destroy
```

and load it from there with almost the same command just switch it to "LOAD" mode

```
/setblock ~ ~ ~ minecraft:structure_block{mode:"LOAD",posY:1,name:"minecraft:autoclone",sizeY:10,sizeX:10,sizeZ:10,author:"<yourname>",showboundingbox:1b} destroy
```

and after each step you need to set a redstone block next to it
the redstone block needs to be set twice for the structure to actually load

```
/setblock ~ ~ ~1 minecraft:redstone_block destroy
```

now just run these with the execute command in the dimension you need

```
/execute in minecraft:overworld run (setblock ..."SAVE"...)
/execute in minecraft:the_nether run (setblock ..."LOAD"...)
```

if the area isn't loaded you can use /forceload ~ ~ to force a chunk's loading

[proof of concept](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8uVUPcxdSXI) 
commands used in the video can be found from the video description

Comment: How would someone go about doing this?

Comment: i've updated it to contain the commands

Comment: Very good answer! I knew structure blocks would be our saviour here. I'll accept this one I've verified its validity in Minecraft.

Comment: muh bounty's gon expire lol

Comment: I'm waiting for validation.  You got 22 hours left anyways.

Comment: i made a proof of concept video to show it in action :)